# deserialize complicated gson string

Tags: android, serialization, gson, deserialization

Hi I hope someone here can help me, I am working in an android app, I already serialize the following gson object

Screenshot:

[image: imggson]

the jsonobject has many subclasses like:
PreferencialaboraEstudio,Preferencialaboralarea, and more classes,

I transfer this gson object from an activity to a new activity, in order to deserialize this object I have implemented the following code in the new activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String Postulado = intent.getStringExtra("Postulado");//Postulado from extra is actually a gson object

Candidato candidato = gson.fromJson(Postulado, Candidato.class);
CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado preflaboraledo = gson.fromJson(Postulado, CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado.class);
```

I have the problem in CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado, as you can see in the picture there are two items of this type class in the gson object, but my code only returns the first item and not the second one, is there a way to get all the items of this type "CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado" from the gson?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: From what I understand you have two objects that happen to be in `Postulado`. I would consider just using two strings, each one with the JSON for each of the objects. It would also be helpful if you can post the structure of the JSON in `Postulado`.

Comment: Yes Postulado is the object and it has many properties/attributes and some of them are Lists, for example CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado, the Gson object has two items in this attribute , so I need to extract these two items of type CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado in a string or list to later add that information in a Textbox or ListView.

Comment: i had tried with this also but still only getting only the first item =/    List<CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado> listaestados = new ArrayList<CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado>();
        listaestados.add(gson.fromJson(Postulado, CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado.class));

Comment: Please if you can - give us the class definition of `Candidato` and `CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado` and the JSON in `intent.getStringExtra("Postulado")` this will really aid anyone in solving this problem. Include all that in the question. Remove any methods from the classes for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your root model is, but you can have something like this:

```
public class Postulado {

    private CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado candidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado;
    private CandidatoSoftware candidatoSoftware;

    public class CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado {
        private List<CandidatoPrefAttributes> candidatoAttributesList;

        public class CandidatoPrefAttributes {
            private Integer cveCandidato;
            private Integer cveCandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado;
            //More
        }

    }

    public class CandidatoSoftware {
        private List<CandidatoSoftwareAttributes> candidatoAttributesList;


        public class CandidatoSoftwareAttributes {
            private Integer cveCandidato;
            private Integer cveCandidatoSoftware;
            //More
        }

    }
}
```

With respective getters.

Also looks that the candidates (CandidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado and CandidatoSoftware) and Candidate Preferences are very similar, maybe you can unify that models to one (Candidate and CandidatePrefferences) and use multiple serialized names like:

```
@SerializedName(value="candidatoPreferenciaLaboralEstado", alternate={"candidatoSoftware"})
```

Hope this can help you!